# How do I assign coordinates from the database to a player?

Tags: mysql, node.js, socket.io, phaser-framework

I can't assign coordinates from the database to the player, although I pass the user via socket.io. I am using mysql 2 and socket.io "4.6.1", I installed them using npm.
There are no errors in the console, the player is simply not displayed.

This is the client code.

```
const socket = io();
  
class BaseScene extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor(key) {
        super({ key });
    }

    preload() {
     this.load.image('player', 'assets/player.png');
    }

    create() {
        this.cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
        socket.on('connection', async (socket) => {
            socket.on('userData', (user) => {
            this.player = this.physics.add.image(x_position, y_position, 'player').setDisplaySize(200, 200);
            });    
          });
    }

    update() {
        if (this.player) {
            if (this.cursors.left.isDown) {
                this.player.setVelocityX(-160);
            } else if (this.cursors.right.isDown) {
                this.player.setVelocityX(160);
            } else {
                this.player.setVelocityX(0);
            }
            if (this.cursors.up.isDown) {
                this.player.setVelocityY(-160);
            } else if (this.cursors.down.isDown) {
                this.player.setVelocityY(160);
            } else {
                this.player.setVelocityY(0);
            }
        }
    }
}

class FirstScene extends BaseScene {
    constructor() {
        super('first');
    }

    preload() {
      super.preload();
    }
    create() {
    super.create();
        
     
    }

    update() {
        super.update();
        
    }
}
```

This is server code.

```
app.get('/profile', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const userId = req.session.user.id;
    const [rows] = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?', [userId]);
    const user = rows[0];
    res.locals.user = user;
    res.render('profile');
    io.on('connection', async (socket) => {
    socket.emit('userData', user);
  });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).send('An error occurred while receiving user data.');
  }
});
```

There are no errors in the console, the player is simply not displayed. If I just create a player with the initial coordinates, then it is displayed, but when I try to assign coordinates from the database, it does not work. How can I assign the coordinates of a player from the database when creating it?

Comment: Are the events on the sokcets being executed? could you confirm this with `console.log` statements?

Comment: I don't understand, the socket logic is inside what looks like an express route handler??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the socket events fire, the problem is only, that you are setting the position of the player to variables, that are not set (or atleast not in this snippet).

As far as I can see `x_position` and `y_position`are never set. Are these maybe properties of the `user` parameter?

```
 socket.on('connection', async (socket) => {
     socket.on('userData', (user) => {
         // this seems to be wrong
         this.player = this.physics.add.image(x_position, y_position, 'player').setDisplaySize(200, 200);
     });    
 });
```

> **Important:** And if you pass `undefined` *(or an other invalid value)* for the `x` and `y` coordinates, nothing will be displayed.